# How to document POST parameters with Apiary?

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary

I've written a small web service that was designed to be "curl-able", so it relies on `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` parameters in `POST` requests, e.g.:

```
curl http://api.example.com/ -d param1=foo -d param2=bar
```

I would like to document this service using [Apiary](https://apiary.io/), but I've been unable to figure out a way to provide structured documentation for these parameters.  I can provide an example request like this...

```
+ Request (application/x-www-form-urlencoded)

        param1=foo&param2=bar
```

...but this doesn't allow me to provide documentation on the
individual parameters (and does not lend itself well to testing in the
apiary console, since it is unable to provide input fields for the
various parameters).

I've read through the [api blueprint specification](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/master/API%20Blueprint%20Specification.md) a few
times and I've been unable to find a good solution.  Is there any way
to provide structured documentation for these parameters?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Attributes](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/master/API%20Blueprint%20Specification.md#def-attributes-section) for this type description.

```
FORMAT: 1A

HOST: http://api.example.com/

# Test attributes 1

## Create post [/]

### Create a Post [POST]

+ Attributes
    + param1: foo (string) - Foo param
    + param2: bar (string) - Bar param

+ Request (application/x-www-form-urlencoded)

+ Response 201
```

Comment: Note we currently do not have url encoded support for rendering the MSON attributes / parameters so you will still need to provide body manually

Comment: Any news if this has been implemented?